# How to run a service as LocalSystem in Windows 7?

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-7, windows-services

I am trying to write my first service application following instructions in Windows SDK. I installed the service using the following code:

```
SC_HANDLE schs=CreateService(sch,
                             SERVICENAME,"VMFS - Servidor de arquivos",
                             SC_MANAGER_CREATE_SERVICE,
                             SERVICE_WIN32_OWN_PROCESS,
                             SERVICE_AUTO_START,
                             SERVICE_ERROR_NORMAL,
                             pathexe,
                             NULL/*LoadOrderGroup*/,
                             NULL/*TagId*/,
                             NULL/*Dependencies*/,
                             NULL/*Account:Local System*/,
                             NULL/*Password*/);
```

> The server does not start(error 1053).

But, if I go to services.msc and change service to logon as my account name (Valdeci), the service starts. So this seems to be a logon error. What is wrong? I want to run my service also in Windows XP and Vista, but didn´t try it because my developing machine has Windows 7.

Comment: LocalSystem is the default account.  I'd focus on debugging your service's Start code so see why it fails when the user account isn't your own.

Comment: I don´t know how to debug the service start code. I use C++ Builder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem! I followed the tips I received: stripped the the code to a "do-nothing" service and it still didn´t work. So I concluded that the problem was not the code itself. The program didn´t even start because of "missing" DLLs. I discovered that "path" works differently when running as LocalSystem, so I copied all my runtime DLLs to the folder of the service. This is the way I normally install my programs, but at development time I use the path.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: My system path didn´t include the path to DLLs. Only user path was set. Now, I made the system path equal user path and don´t need to copy my DLLs to service path.

Answer (score 1):

Try using NULL instead of ".\\LocalSystem", as described in the [CreateService documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682450%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) .

Comment: I tried that and did´t work, I changed for ".\\LocalSystem" but didn´t work either.

Comment: Your service is starting but isn't reporting its status in a timely fashion (that's what 1053 means). What does your code do in ServiceMain(), the function called to start your service? Does it access the network, a mapped drive, the registry, etc.? Try stripping it down as much as possible to debug the situation.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will try to reduce the code to the minimum to see if it works. But, as I said, when I change the account to my personal account it works and my ServiceMain report the status quickly.

Comment: OK. The things I mentioned (accessing mapped drives, reading the registry) operate differently for each user and may explain why the service works in your account but not in LocalSystem.